# SqlException: Login failed for user ''. on ASP.NET CORE 1.0.1 APP in IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, .net-core

I am setting up an ASP.NET CORE 1.0.1 in a Windows 2012 R2 environment on IIS 8. The application connects to an SQL database and has a connection string in the application.json file (info changed):

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database": "Data Source=qadb;Initial Catalog=companydb;Trusted_Connection=True"
},
```

In IIS, I've set up the application and the application pool has been set to run as a certain user (say company\sqluser). I verified that company\sqluser has read/write access to the database. The advanced settings for the application pool look as such:

```
.NET CLR Version: No Managed Code
Enable 32-bit Application: False
Managed Pipeline Mode: Integrated
Identity: company\sqluser
```

When I run the application, I get the following SQL error message:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.
```

I would like to have the application connect to the DB as company\sqluser, but for some reason it doesn't seem like it is able to do so. I've also tried running the application pool as my personal user account which has admin rights to the SQL DB and still get the error.

Am I missing a certain configuration?

EDIT: My web.config file is as follows:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
 </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\CompanyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="*" /><conditions><add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
              </conditions><action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to follow below [article](https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Using-Windows-Authentication-to-access-SQL-Server-Secret-Server) to know how to use AD domain whth IIS application pool to access sql database.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Integrated Security=true` instead of `Trusted_Connection=True` in your connection string.

`Integrated Security=true` is the syntax for System.Data.SqlClient, while `Trusted_Connection=true` is the syntax for ODBC.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netcore-1.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax

Comment: That didn't work either. Still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 2):

As I am not the developer for the application, I didn't realize that the developer overwrote the connection string in the code instead of using the appsettings.json file. What was missing was the following:

```
Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Once I removed the code that overwrote the connection string and made sure that Trusted_Connection was set to True in the appsettings, the application worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting Windows authentication. In IIS, make sure that the windows authentication module is added and enabled on.

Also, need to ensure app pool is running under domain account not local account.

In ASP.net, we usually do like this:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
 </system.web>
```

In Asp.net core, this way usually works:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Hi Gauravsa, I've tried adding the authentication mode as Windows in the web.config file and disabling Anonymous Authentication. That didn't work either.